# EventListener Example from "The Good Parts"

Tags: javascript, yui

I'm a JavaScript Newbie.
I needed to add an EventListener to Node.on('click', foo); and my first try was - of course - a FAIL:

```
var i = 0;
Y.one('#btnDel' + i).on('click', function () {
    Y.one('#part' + i).remove(true);
});
```

Than i rememberred that something like that was in the "JavaScript: The Good Parts" Book, and i found it (Page 39):

```
var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
        nodes[i].onclick = function (i) {
            return function (e) {
                alert(e);
            };
         }(i);
     }
};
```

But that doesn't work either. By a second (more 21th) look, there was something wrong for me: You return an inner function who needs an argument 'e', but 'i' isn't called to the inner function - just to the outer one.
I "fixed" this and now it works in my case with YUI:

```
 Y.one('#btnDel' + i).on('click', function (i) {
    return function () {
        Y.one('#part' + i).remove(true);
    }
}(i));
```

On the [on the errata pakge](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596517748), someone wrote this "fix" too. But the Author (Crockford!) still persist on the book-version. Is there something I oversee - and it's just a coincidence that my version works in my case?

ps: When I bound `i` in my anonymous-return function to `this.i`, then this would be the global object?

pps: sorry for my great english. :|

Answer (score 2):

...or use event delegation: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/node/node-evt-delegation.html.

1) You will end up with only one event listener that will delegate to desired elements (in you case buttons),
2) It will work much better with dynamic content. If you add another element (eg. button) later you don't have to attach another listener to it. It is already handled by delegation.

...and the example you are referring to (Page 39) is a typical closure which is a gotcha for most of the newcomers. So no worries. You have figured out the solution by yourself which is impressive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to collect all your buttons with a class selector. Then you can simply use the 'each' function:

```
Y.all(".buttonClassName").each(function (oneButtonNode) {
    oneButtonNode.on("click", function (event) {
        //do something
        alert(this.get("id"));
    })
});
```

YUI3 docu: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/node/#nodelist

Answer (score 0):

Because i is defined outside the loop, but is not evaluated in the subscriber function until the click happens.  That same i was incremented until it was equal to node.length.  So when the click happens, i is node.length.  This is a common error for developers new to JavaScript.  See http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/closures-in-javascript/ for details about what's going on.

As to a solution, use event delegation: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/delegation.html